# Ways of Proving invertibility of $3 \times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know only two way in **proving** invertibility of matrices which is by using determinant and making the matrices into row echelon form. Are there any other ways to **prove** invertibility of matrices?

Example of invertible $3 \times 3$ matrices
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 1& 0& 2 \\ 3& 1& 6\\ 8& 9& 2 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Example of non-invertible $3 \times 3$ matrices

$$\left( \begin{matrix} 1& 2& 3\\ 4& 5& 6\\ 1& 2& 3 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647288/matrices-find-the-rank-and-determine-if-its-invertible/647296#647296)

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) has a nice list of answers to your questions.

Letting $A$ be a square matrix, I think some of the nicer ones on the list are,

- The equation $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution $x = 0$.
- The number $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.
- The columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Comment: The statement about eigen-values is just a re-statement of the first point, right?

Comment: All of the statements in the list are actually equivalent so in that sense the answer is "yes". The proof of equivalency is pretty straightforward: If $Ax=0$ has only the solution $x=0$ then $0$ is not an eigenvalue $A$ (since $0$ would have no corresponding eigenvector). On the other hand, if $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ then, that means the kernel is trivial, which means the only solution to $Ax=0$ is $x=0$.

Comment: And it is because that the proof is so straightforward that I thought it would be trivial to add that point. But it is not a big matter in fact.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean. Nevertheless, I felt the two statements had distinct enough "feels" that it would be nice to state both, even if the equivalence was trivial.

Comment: OK. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In addition one should note that for square matrices in $M_n(K)$, in addition to the determinant, the field is important, too.
For example, the first matrix 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \cr
3 & 1 & 6 \cr
8 & 9 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is **not** invertible over a field of characteristic $2$ or $7$, because in this case
the determinant $\det(A)=-14=0$. This arises, for example, in coding theory.