# Matrices - Find the rank and determine if its invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the rank of $A = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&-4\\-4&-1&-6\\-2&2&-2\end{bmatrix}$ and explain why $A$ is not invertible.

What I have done is:

Guass-Jordan Elimination: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, I found the $rank(A) = 2$

Explanation why $A$ is invertible:

A matrix i invertible if and only if it does not have $0$ as any number such that a given matrix minus that number times the identity matrix has a $0$ dominant. Since this does not satisfy $A$, $A$ is not invertible.

Am I right with both answers? My explanation on whether or not $A$ is invertible is not strong, I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In particular for matrices 3x3, given

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$$

The inverse is

$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(A)}\begin{bmatrix}ei-fh&ch-bi&bf-ce\\fg-di&ai-cg&cd-af\\dh-ge&bg-ah&ae-bd\end{bmatrix}$$

and since the determinant of a matrix without full rank is $0$ you have that $\frac{1}{det(A)}"=" "\frac{1}{0}"$ and thus the inverse does not exist :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the rank. I do not know what a dominant is. For the second point I would say that a square matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is nonzero or, equivalently, if and only if it is of maximal rank. Since your matrix is not of maximal rank it is not invertible. Otherwise, after you have reduced the matrix to upper triangular form via Gauss elimination, you can compute the determinant multiplying the elements on the diagonal: from this you see that the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 1):

you're right, you can use that a matrix is invertible iff it's rank is full.